# How to parse an JSON Empty Key Value in iOS?

Tags: ios, json

i am newbie in iOS Development i make an application of JSON Data parsing in my web-services i make a Dictionary and its key like as

```
NSDictionary *dict = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
```

and my key is like as

```
NSString *content=[dict valueForKey:@"post_content"];
cell.descripLabel.text=content;
```

in my web-services my "post_content":false then error in

```
cell.descripLabel.text=content;
```

How i solve it?????

Comment: @rmaddy eroor is like as "[__NSCFBoolean length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking from you response to other questions your JSON is actually returning a BOOLEAN, not an empty value, try this...

```
id content=[dict valueForKey:@"post_content"];
if([content isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
    cell.descripLabel.text = content;    
} else {
    cell.descripLabel.text =  @"";
}
```